# flot: can not use line-chart overview on narrow screen

Tags: flot

- In the 'overview' chart I display data of 3 months X 30 days X 24 hours X 6 samples every hour.
- In the 'main' chart I display, by default, data of the last day, or data of selected range in the 'overview' or data of selected date.
- On regular desktop screen it works well.

I now tried to adapt this project into responsive design, and show the charts according to the screen size.

my problem: On narrow screen, when the range in the 'overview' is too small (measured in pixels?), I do not get the overview plotselected event.

- If I try to dispaly the default last day - I dont get the plotselected event.
- If I try to select one day on my date picker - I dont get the plotselected event.
- If I try to select data of 3-last-days, it does work well.
- If I change to wide screen, all works well.

How can I force 'overview' selection?

In the image below, one can see selection of last-3-days. this works. but selection of last-1-day does not work:

[image]

Comment: You should show your code when asking a quedtion like this.

Comment: my code is based on flot-overview-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flot selection plugin has a `minSize` option which is by default set to 5 pixels. Since one day of data in your overview is about 3 pixels wide the `plotselected` event does not fire. Set the `minSize` to 1 and it should work with a chart of size down to 100 pixels.

From the comments in the **jquery.flot.selection.js** file:

> "minSize" is the minimum size a selection can be in pixels. This value can
>   be customized to determine the smallest size a selection can be and still
>   have the selection rectangle be displayed. When customizing this value, the
>   fact that it refers to pixels, not axis units must be taken into account.
>   Thus, for example, if there is a bar graph in time mode with BarWidth set to 1
>   minute, setting "minSize" to 1 will not make the minimum selection size 1
>   minute, but rather 1 pixel. Note also that setting "minSize" to 0 will prevent
>   "plotunselected" events from being fired when the user clicks the mouse without
>   dragging.

Comment: so if 1 day is less than one pixel, I cannot use date-picker to select a day in 'overview' and let it handle the event ?! what is the solution for such case? ignore the 'overview' and select the mainplot directly?

Comment: You can try setting the `minSize` to 0, but that has side effects (see the qoute in the answer).